# Is it possible to use the GD Library with actual images?

Tags: php, gd

I'd like to use the GD Library with actual images - BLOBs from a mysql database.
Can it be done? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: To answer your main question: Yes.

Comment: I'm a little curious why you're saving images in the database though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

It accepts an image as string data, auto-detects its type (as long as it's supported of course) and creates a GD resource based on it.